# Django - Images are overlapping

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

im currently developing a Django app where i need to display an histogram in the template for the current exam, the problem is that the images are overlapping if i see more than one exam. I will show in the images below.
This is the histogram correspondent to the first exam i check
[image]

And if i check another exam this is the histogram that appears:
[image]

But if i restart the server it shows OK like the next picutre.[image]

Does anybody knows why this is happening? ill post the code of the image display

```
def showImage(request,exam_id):
  imagePath = '/home/luis/Documentos/projeto/media/examshist/hist'+exam_id+'.png'
  Image.init()
  i = Image.open(imagePath)

  response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
  i.save(response,'PNG')
  return response
```

Comment: I guess the problem is not in the snippet you posted. Where are you generating the image? Also, if it is pre-generated your webserver is way more efficient serving it - consider generating the images under MEDIA_ROOT and just returning a redirect.

Comment: yes the problem was in the histogram creation, i forgot to close the figure, its all fixed now

Comment: Add your answer as an answer, not as a comment.